# Как правильно вернуть *handle функцией

Tags: c++, usb

Здравствуйте.
Есть объявление структуры

```
struct hid_device_;
typedef struct hid_device_ hid_device; /**< opaque hidapi structure */
```

Есть объявление дескриптора

```
hid_device *device_handle;
```

И его определение

```
handle = hid_open(0x4d8, 0x3f, NULL);
```

Как мне правильно сделать функцию, возвращающую дескриптор?

Пробовал

```
hid_device foo(void)
{
   hid_device *device_handle;
   handle = hid_open(0x4d8, 0x3f, NULL);
   returnt device_handle;
}
```

Но пишет ошибку function returns incomplete type. Как мне сделать определение дескриптора внутри функции?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`device_handle` - это *указатель* на структуру типа `handle`, а не сама структура. У вас неверно указан тип возвращаемого значения `foo`:

```
hid_device* foo(void)
{
   hid_device *device_handle;
   device_handle = hid_open(0x4d8, 0x3f, NULL);
   return device_handle;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло.